# Install php-curl in Openwrt

Tags: php, curl, openwrt, php-curl

I have to install `php5-curl` in my OpenWrt. I followed the steps of the [official site](https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/uci/uhttpd#using_php5)

When I type, I see available packages:

```
$ opkg list php5*
```

but, I don't see `php5-culr` or `php-curl`. However, I change the line:

```
;extension=sockets.so
```

To:

```
extension=sockets.so
```

In `php.ini` file And also, add a file `php_curl.ini` in `etc/php5/` and restart the server (`lighttpd`) and nothing happened. 
Any help to get CURL in OpenWrt?

Comment: Package installations aren't programming questions just because it's about a programming language. And if curl is neither compiled in, nor available, then that's that. Updating is sometimes an option though: https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/php7-mod-curl

Comment: in my case is not an option. the client application works on php5 and they handle a special version that they compile from openwrt. :(

Comment: The good news is that the OpenWRT build system is somewhat unwieldy, but still available for older releases, and you can recompile and package PHP yourself. (If "works on php5" is not just an euphemism for not having even tried to port or conflating the versions for entirely distinct languages.)